# How to create Fibonacci series in python using objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, fibonacci

I'm learning objects in python.  I'm trying to write python code for the fibonacci series.

```
class palindrome:
    p=0
    q=1
    r=0
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number=number

    def calc(self):
        p=0
        q=1
        r=0
        if (self.number == 1):
            print "0 1"
        for i in range(3,1):
            r = p + q
            p = q
            q = r
            print " %d " %r

pal = palindrome("1")
print pal.number()
```

When I run this program with different values it shows an error.  If I pass an object 1 then it does not print 001 and also if I pass in some how do I print something for the 1st time and never print it again. for example 0 1 in fibonacci series.

So when I try to put this statement in for loop 'for I (3, self.number)' it throws an error saying that you cannot define a string in int. So how do I pass in the value of object in the for loop. Also how do I compare self.number == 1 and print the message.

Comment: self.number is a string, did you mean `pal = palindrome(1)`. Why are you starting at 3? Did you also mean `print pal.calc()`

Comment: I'm starting from 3 because by defult 0 , 1 , 1 should be printed. what ever the user selects..

Comment: But for any number > 1 it never prints 0 1, did you mean `if self.number > 0`

Comment: My bad for both it should print 0 0 1 . That's how fibonnaci series are designed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be coming from a C or Java background where there is an inherent difference **in the language** between the "primitive" types such as int, and "Object" types such as String.
Further, these *compiled* languages have "static typing" where variables are declared with a type.

**In python, it's completely different.** *Everything* is an object. Types are **not known** statically.

With that in mind, let's trace the execution of your code:

```
pal = palindrome("1") # Creates a ojbect of type string with the value "1"
                      # Creates a palindrome object named pal.
                      # Calls palindrome's __init__ to construct pal
```

Descending into `palindrome`...

```
class palindrome:
    p = 0
    q = 1
    r = 0
    # These are like Java's static varialbes, NOT member variables
    def __init__(self,number): # number is the STRING OBJECT "1"
        self.number = number # Copies the string "1" to self.number, a member variable
```

That's it for the constructor, ascnding back to main...

```
print pal.number() # pal.number is a string, but you are calling it as if it
                   # is a function. This would work if string objects were 'callable'
```

But the so-called "builtin" type `str` does not define a calling mechanism. Running the exact code you have shown should result in this error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

---

**Now, to answer your specific questions**:

```
if (self.number == 1):
    print "0 1"
```

This check must fail because `self.number` has the value `"1"` -- a string object, but you are comparing it to `1` -- an int object. Hence "0 1" is not printed

```
for i in range(3,1):
    ...
```

Since 3 is greater than 1, this evaluates to an empty range and the loop does not run

```
for i in range(3, self.number):
```

`range()` expects two `int`-s, but again `self.number` is a string. Therefore you should see this error: `TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str`. To convert a `str` to an `int`:

```
for i in range(3, int(self.number)):
```

The value of `self.number` is dynamically cast into an int. This would fail if `self.number` is not an appropriate string to be translated into an int, such as "abc" rather than "1".

Comment: I get it now but still no results can't run my code. ' Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\palindrome.py", line 26, in <module>
    print palindrome()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: `palindrome()` invokes the class constructor, the `__init__()` function, and returns a `palindrome` object. The code in your original question invokes it correctly `pal = palindrome(<something>)` -- I think what you want is to change the next line from `pal.number()` to `pal.calc()`

Comment: And of course, `pal = palindrome("1")` should be `pal = palindrome(1)`

Comment: Now I have everything in place. Now my problem is that for loop is not iterating as expected. The Out put is not as expected as to be. Palindrome is what i have named it but actully its fibonacci which i'm trying to print. 
'
class palindrome:
    p=0
    q=1
    r=0
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number=number

    def calc(self):
        p=0
        q=1
        r=0
        if (self.number == 1):
            print "0 1"
        for i in range(3,int(self.number)):
            r = p + q
            p = q
            q = r
            print r


pal = palindrome(4)
print pal.calc()
'

Comment: Yes !! The code Now works. Now at the beginning of the execution i need to add this 0 0 1 in the begining. and then append the results of r. Any trick or logic how to get it .

Comment: Finally with this logic and with your help i could get the expected output but if you have something better in mind. Do point out. 

`import math
class palindrome:
    p=0
    q=1
    r=0
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number=number

    def calc(self):
        p=0
        q=1
        r=0
        if (self.number == 1):
            print "0 1"
        else:
            print 0
            print 1
            for i in range(0,(self.number)):
                r = p + q
                p = q
                q = r
                print r


pal = palindrome(15)
print pal.calc()
`

Comment: @user3079582 Your solution seems fine. I'm sure there are better options out there, but none come to mind